# Can't find servers in Data Connection in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, explorer, localdb

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

I'm following the tutorial in the link above, and when I get to the step "Connect to either LocalDb ((localdb)\v11.0) or SQL Express (.\SQLEXPRESS), depending on which one you have installed" in the "Where's my data" section, the server name drop down is blank. I have LocalDB installed, and the program is writing to a database since following the previous steps of the tutorial I created two tables that were saved, but for some reason I can't add a connection to any server in Database Explorer.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's blank it means you never set it up before so add it manually, if you are not sure what to put as the server name you can try `.`

Comment: I have LocalDB installed. How do I get "(localdb)\v11.0" to appear in the server drop down as shown in the tutorial?

Comment: LocalDB is the database not the servername, the server name is what goes in the first dropdown, once you select it, the second dropdown will be enable and populated with the databases name such as localDB, SQL express ..

Comment: Thanks for answering. I played around some more and I was able to figure it out along with learning about connection strings.

Comment: @ShadowCrossZero what did you do to fix this? I'm following the same tutorial and having the same issue

Comment: @Abdul the best way is to use the connection wizard